# _winreg.SaveKey Error - A required privilege is not held by the client

Tags: python, registry, privileges, winreg

I want to save the registry key "Run" using _winreg in Python.
This is my code:

```
import _winreg
key = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run')
_winreg.SaveKey(key, "C:\key.reg")
```

When executing, I get a Windows error message: "A required privilege is not held by the client"

Can anyone see what is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify your code as below. It works fine if it is `Run as Administrator`. I have tested it on Win7 64 bit

```
import os, sys
import _winreg
import win32api
import win32security

#
# You need to have SeBackupPrivilege enabled for this to work
#

priv_flags = win32security.TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | win32security.TOKEN_QUERY
hToken = win32security.OpenProcessToken (win32api.GetCurrentProcess (), priv_flags)
privilege_id = win32security.LookupPrivilegeValue (None, "SeBackupPrivilege")
win32security.AdjustTokenPrivileges (hToken, 0, [(privilege_id, win32security.SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED)])

key = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, r'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run')

filepath = r'C:\key.reg'

if os.path.exists (filepath):
  os.unlink (filepath)

_winreg.SaveKey (key, filepath)
```

**Note**: if `win32api` & `win32security` are missing, install them from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20219/)

Reference: [Here](https://code.google.com/p/python-on-windows-docs/source/browse/trunk/trunk/programming-areas/registry/save_the_registry.py?r=3)